# plsql procedure: Not able to get pctfree and ini_trans values from dba_tables

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

in oracle i am logged in as system user and i am using sql developer.

i want to access pct_free values and ini_trans values from dba_tables for particular table.

the plsql code procedure is written as(simple version program):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findattributes(tablename in varchar2) IS
  pct dba_tables.pct_free%type;
  initrans dba_tables.ini_trans%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT PCT_FREE, INI_TRANS INTO pct, initrans FROM dba_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMP';
END;
```

the above code gives me compilation error such as statement ignored(for 'SELECT'), missing expression near('pct' inside begin statement)

if i run as normal sql query it returns me values but why is this not working in case of plsql.

i am using oracle blackbook as reference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a case of privileges granted by role. See [This article by Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551289900368934430) for an explanation. Procedures don't inherit the privileges granted by roles.

Comment: no thjs cant be problem because dba_table is accessible with simple query.
why would it cause problem with plsql.
moreover i am logged in as system user.

Comment: Does the query work if you specify `SET ROLE NONE` before executing it? Also what precise compilation error exactly do you get?

Comment: i get error like : ERROR(6,3) SQL statement ignored.
ERROR(6,35) missigng expression.